# Terminology of AC -DC converters

Tags: power-electronics, inverter, converter, ac-dc

I would like to ask about the difference between the terms "AC-DC Converter", "DC-AC Converter" and "Inverter".

If I am getting it right, the "AC-DC converter" converters AC voltage to DC.
The "DC-AC converter" turns DC into AC.
The inverter can do both?
 To be more specific I am working on this configuration:

[image]

This topology is characterized by four-quadrant operation. Some authors call it "Three - phase voltage source Inverter" while other "Bidirectional AC-DC Converter". Which is the proper terminology ?

Comment: "Inverter" can mean anything so, please provide some context by linking a web definition to this question.

Comment: @Andyaka I edited the question in order to provide more information.

Comment: I asked for a link. Link to the article where the picture came from maybe?

Comment: @Andyaka https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324490141_HIL_co-simulation_of_finite_set-model_predictive_control_using_FPGA_for_a_three-phase_VSI_system

Comment: I'm not a member.

Comment: An ac-dc converter is a dc-dc converter preceded by a diode bridge and a bulk capacitor which perform the ac-to-dc conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schematic shows a basic 3 phase **inverter** with back-EMF clamp diodes which may also be used with a generator to convert AC to DC and appropriate changes in phase-control of gates. With that additional application in mind, it can support bi-direction conversion.

The DC to AC conversion feature alone is most commonly referred to as an AC Inverter.

The article entitled ***HIL co-simulation of finite set-model predictive control using FPGA for a three-phase VSI system***  is a post-graduate level article that does not focus on these basic controls. These are perhaps better described in your beginner electronics textbook or in Wiki.